# Decrypt only alphas in a string

Tags: python-3.x

I want to decrypt a string by incrementing each letter by two alpha positions *i.e.* 'a' becomes 'c'. I've used `chr` and `ord` for the increments but can't work out how to skip over the special characters in the string such as spaces and parenthesis.

```
from sys import stdout
from time import sleep

encodedString = 'g fmnc wms'

stringLength = len(encodedString)

for i in range(0, stringLength):
    if encodedString[i].isalpha():
        decodedString = chr(ord(encodedString[i]) + 2)
        stdout.write("\r%s" % decodedString)
        stdout.flush()
        sleep(0.1)
stdout.write("\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

you may want to check out a different approach, resulting in a much simpler code: using a regular expression to catch all the letters and replace them. Something like this:

```
import re

encodedString = 'g fmnc wms'

def decodeLetter(match):
    letter = match.group(0)[0]
    if letter in 'YZyz':
        return chr(ord(letter) - 24)
    else:
        return chr(ord(letter) + 2)

print(re.sub('[a-zA-Z]', decodeLetter, encodedString))
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Just for kicks, here's another way to do it:

```
encodedString = 'g fmnc wms'

alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
capalphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
decodedString = ""

for i in range(len(encodedString)):
    if encodedString[i] in alphabet:
        decodedString += alphabet[i+2]
    elif encodedString[i] in capalphabet:
        decodedString += alphabet[i+2]
    else:
        decodedString += encodedString[i]

print(decodedString)
```

Comment: This would throw an exception if there are the letters y or z, but since there is no specification what to do if these characters are present, it accurately models what you're asking for.